# defend from vs. defend against

Tags: prepositions

> I want to defend society and its **inhabitants** **from** all
>   ideologies, science included.
>   <sup>[source](http://www.calpoly.edu/~fotoole/321.1/feyer.html)</sup>

Would you tell me what the preposition **from** means here?

Although I have seen and known the preposition **of** might mean **against**, in fact, my profs. has just told me :

> the preposition **from** in this sentence **never ever** means
>   **against**, it means just **of**.

Do you know why?

Because if you want to put the preposition of, then you must put a **noun of place** after the word inhabitants! for example:

**Inhabitants of India**   ***not inhabitants from India***

And, as there is not any place, so we have to put the preposition from instead of of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good question, Nima! First, [see](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from) one of the senses for **from**

> —used as a function word to indicate physical separation or an act or condition of removal, abstention, exclusion, release, subtraction, or differentiation (**protection from the sun**, relief from anxiety)

Hence, in the sentence

> I want to defend society and all of its members **from** all ideologies, science included.

the meaning of *from* equals to *against*, in my view.

However, if in place of *ideologies, science included* we use phrases like *all ideological strata* or *all ideological groups* or *all congregations* etc., the meaning of *from* would change, as I see it. Compare:

> I want to defend society and all of its members **from** all ideological strata, including those who pursue science as their chief interest.

In this case, the reader will assume that what's meant here is that the members *come* or *originate* from diverse ideological strata, or demographic groups, or ideological groups, or whatever.

Try googling `protect people from all`, and you will get sentences like

> Our organization helps protect people **from** all walks of life / all backgrounds ..

Here, the people are clearly not being protected *from* walks of life but rather *belong* to these walks of life.

Comment: First thanks. Nevertheless, originally why did not the writer write the word its members instead of inhabitants? I think  they could but they avoid it. Consecuently, from does not mean against, does it?

Comment: *Members* seemed more idiomatic to me. A society is not a tangible thing like a building, say. Regarding your second question, see Definition 2 here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from

Comment: I really do appreciate your Great explanations. Nevertheless, I can not yet accept them inclusively!

Comment: Nevertheless, If "from" is a shortened way of saying "who come from" then is  my prof right?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm not a native speaker. I'm not sure that one could *come from an ideology*. One could come *from a school of thought*. There should be some word marking the belonging of the person to a group of people, IMHO.

Comment: It could perhaps, if the sentence was used in other circumstances. But in your source, even the title of the reading assignment ("How to Defend Society **Against** Science") clearly indicates that the author used *from* as a synonym for *against*, not as a synonym for *of* or *who come from*.

Answer (score 7):

Your professor is wrong. In this context *from* is indeed synonymous with *against*. There's no hard and fast rule as to which one should be used.

Comment: No hard and fast rule, except that you can't say "never ever" like the prof did.

Comment: I would not consider "from" and "against" synonymous.  To "protect against" X is to prevent X from occurring.  To "protect from: X is to prevent X from causing damage.  In 1944, the RAF protected London against German bombing raids, while shelters protected its inhabitants from them.  To the extent that the RAF could prevent German planes from reaching London, they prevented raids.  Shelters didn't prevent raids, but prevented injuries the raids would otherwise have caused.

Comment: It is just as valid to say bomb shelters protect against bombs...